# how to send Django view response to modal?

Tags: python, django, django-views

Im trying to create note detail in modal popup window.

Here is  the modal invoke **anchor tag**

```
         <a class="fa fa-pencil" data-toggle="modal" href="{% url 'post_detail_view' %}"  data-id="{{ todo_item.content }}" data-target="#modal" title="edit item" data-tooltip></a>
```

here is the view function in **views.py**:

```
def post_detail_view(request, content):
    all_items1 = TodoItem.objects.get(content=content)

    return render(request, 'todo.html', {'all_items1': all_items1})
```

here is my **urls.py** :

```
    path('post_detail_view/<str:content>/', views.post_detail_view, name='post_detail_view'),
```

This is my modal code in **todo.html**

```html
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
      <form action="/addTodo/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         {% csrf_token %}
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabe2">Edit Info</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            {% if all_items1 %}
            <label for="content">Title :</label><br>
            <p>{{ all_items1.content }}</p>
            <p>{{ all_items1.data }}</p>
            <input type="text" id='c' name="content" value="{{ all_items1.content }}"/><br>
            <label for="data">Description :</label><br>
            <textarea id="data" rows="4" cols="50" value="">{{ all_items1.data }}</textarea>
            <br>
            <label for="tags">Tags :</label><br>
            <input type="tags" name="tags" value="{{ all_items1.tags }}"/><br>
            <a href="{{ all_items1.file.url }}">
            {% load static %}
            <img src="{% static 'ico.png' %}" style="width:30px;height:30px" alt="download">
            </a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            {% endif %}
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

This code is not working. I can see modal is popping up but no data is displayed. I'm still learning Django. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your parameter is not passing to view layer. try this:

```
 <a class="fa fa-pencil" data-toggle="modal" href="{% url 'post_detail_view' todo_item.content %}" data-target="#modal" title="edit item" data-tooltip></a>
```